# Excel Formula For Time Season

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new to this forum. I had a column of months, obtained from the column of dates. My task was then to convert this column of months into the one of season. While performing the task on my own, I produced the formula empirically:

=@IFS(OR([@Sünnikuu] = {"Detsember","Jaanuar","Veebruar"}),"Talv",OR([@Sünnikuu] = {"Märts","Aprill","Mai"}),"Kevad",OR([@Sünnikuu] = {"Juuni","Juuli","August"}),"Suve",OR([@Sünnikuu] = {"September","Oktoober","November"}),"Sügis")

As you may see, there are used things like @,#,[],{},!. What is the purpose of these symbols in Excel?

This formula checks if the month corresponds to a specific season. For example, if the month is January, then it is winter. My work is in Estonian.

Comment: `{}` indicate and array, `[]` are used with structured references. `@` makes it an implicit reference.

Comment: What is understood by implicit reference? In my work, without the @ formula did not work at all.

Comment: Explicit: `=A1` Implicit `=@A1:A4` It will return the value of the row the formula is in. [Sünnikuu] returns the full column, by adding the `@` it will return one value, the one that is in the same row as the formula.

Comment: See: https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection

Comment: a simpler formula: `=CHOOSE(INT((MATCH(LEFT([@Sünnikuu],4),{"Dets","Jaan","Veeb","Märt","Apri","Mai","Juun","Juul","Augu","Septe","Okto","Nove"},0)-1)/3)+1,"Talv","Kevad","Suve","Sügis")`

Comment: Is there another way to pass by the formula CHOOSE and TEXT(data, mmmm)?

Comment: if your data are dates: `=CHOOSE(INT((MONTH(EDATE(data,1))-1)/3)+1,"Talv","Kevad","Suve","Sügis")`

Comment: "what you think about the formula" is not generally a good question in this site. This is a q&a site for helping each other. To get best help, please :share sample input data, explain what your formula does currently, and also explain what should it do instead.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I worked with the site Math Stack Exchange and in Physics one. People prefer provides understanding, so we would know more about life, but not help solve homework for another person. So, I wrote what the formula and asked what  those symbols mean, and is that a good formula, implying there might be more advanced and simple one - because I worked with Excel without Internet help, I encountered those symbols and something worked, something did not. My formula makes from the month name the season one. I had a column of months and had to create one for seasons.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Eitherway, I have acquired the answers to my question, so I should edit the question so that it would be answered and not delete it - I know deletion is not good option. Have a great day and be happy, healthy.